# tensorflow shift image and interpolate

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, data-augmentation

I am trying to shift all images in a batch and have 'NEAREST' interpolation. For some reason, the resulting images are interpolated with black pixels... Is this a bug?

```
 translations = [100,0] * len(img_batch_list)
 img_batch = tf.contrib.image.translate(img_batch,
                                        translations,
                                        interpolation='NEAREST',
                                        name="shift")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a bug. As per https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/translate 
It's because empty space due to the translation will be filled with zeros. Zeros will be displayed as black color.

Comment: so where does the NEAREST interpolation come in?

Comment: I believe it is because of your image/translations combination. I've just tested on random images and depending on translation received different result, including black pixels